# Error compiling CSS when Susy 2 present ... Line 131 of _grid.scss: Function gutter takes 1 argument but 2 were passed

Tags: susy-compass, codekit

I have two Susy 1 projects, one compiles AOK with all versions the other throws an error if I use the latest versions of CodeKit that support Susy 2, I am treating both projects s Susy 1 projects and so I change the `susy` line to `susyone` when using the Susy 2 CodeKit.

In main.scss I have

`// when using CodeKit pre Susy 2 build:
@import "compass";
@import "susy";`

`// when using CodeKit Susy 2 build:
@import "compass";
@import "susyone";`

The error one project has when I use the Susy 2 supporting version of CodeKit is:

`Compass was unable to compile one or more files in the project:
error main.scss (Line 131 of _grid.scss: Function gutter takes 1 argument but 2 were passed.)
overwrite main.css`

FWIW I have no _grid.scss so I assume that's part of Susy (or Compass).

I've not been able to find an answer from research and experiments.

Tks in advance for any comments. Cheers, -Alan

Comment: That's odd. The `gutter()` function should take 2 arguments. Any chance `gutter()` is being defined somewhere else in your code (or in another plugin) and overriding the Susy function? If you look at the output `main.css`, it will show you a more complete traceback for the error. Does that provide any more leads?

Comment: I can't find any instance of "gutter(" anywhere in the entire project but I checked the compiled main.css after the error and saw this (paths shortened):

`Syntax error: Function gutter takes 1 argument but 2 were passed.
        on line 131 of /.../CodeKit.app/Contents/Resources/engines/susy/sass/susy/language/susyone/_grid.scss, in `span-columns'
        from line 83 of /Users/alan/.../_layout.scss
        from line 42 of /Users/alan/.../main.scss`

Those lines are: (see next comment, running out of space here)

Comment: Line 42:
`@import "partials/layout";`

Line 83:
`.template_home .contentMajor {
// @include span-columns(8, 12, $grid-padding);
@include span-columns(6, 12, $grid-padding);
}`

Hope that helps and sorry if format here in a comment block is too broken, if so I can pastebin or similar. And THANK YOU for the fast reply Eric, I am SO wanting to move to Susy 2 ^_^ Cheers, -Alan

Comment: Yeah, pastebin might be a good idea. This isn't making much sense to me yet, but I'm happy to help track it down if I can.

Comment: Thank you kindly Eric for the offer to check pastebin, I took a second run at it and have successfully converted the project to Susy 2 and so sidestepped the problem ^_^ Susy 2 is fabulous; thank you and contributors _very_ much for making it, I am most grateful. Cheers, -Alan

Comment: Glad to hear it. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Okay i ran into this Problem too today.

After a lot back and forth trying i found one file that included

```
@import "susy";
```

since we're using susy 2 we need to include

```
@import "susyone";
```

as there were 2 includes (susy and susyone) in different files the compilation of the css files failed.